# Calculating the distance from bottom to the current position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate the diistance from the bottom the the window to the current scroll position. I have used the following code ( [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SKN69/2/) ) :-

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   var height= $(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop();
   $(".height").html(height);
 });
```

The ouput when I scroll to the bottom must be **0**. But, the output is something greater than 400. Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/JASbZ/)

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     //for fiddle
     var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();

     //to test on real website
     //var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height()
     $(".height").html(height);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should take in account the window height aswell. In the end, the calculus will return you the answer for this question:
*How many pixels is **the end of the visible area** far from the bottom of the page?*

If that fits OK for you, then this code will do it:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".height").text(bottom + "px from the bottom of the page");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ns4gr/)

Comment: your answer was equally good..But unfortunately, had to tick 1 best answer

Comment: NP, is up to you to decide the best fit.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$(document).height()` and `$(window).height()` are consts !
you want to cache them and not calc them each scroll tick :

```
var _d= $(document).height() ;
var _w= $(window).height() ;
//you can also cache (if you want) $(window) , $('.height')


 $(window).scroll(function(){

     var height=_d - _w - $(window).scrollTop();
     $(".height").html(height);
 });
```

You don't want those repeats :

[image]

**However** you'd need to do this :

```
$(window).on('resize',function (){ _w= $(window).height() });
```

Comment: Actually, the better answer would be not using jQuery at all :)